# Why will HashMap ignore entries with keys from the same Superclass?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, hashmap

I have created a map with maps inside as a test and it seems that the outer map will ignore the rest of the maps. I assume it is overriding them. Also I presume that it is because they all extend from Map so it is treating them as the same instance when they are not.

```
Map<Map<Integer, String>,String> maps=new HashMap<>();
maps.put(new HashMap<Integer, String>(),"HashMap");
maps.put(new TreeMap<Integer, String>(),"TreeMap");
maps.put(new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>(),"LinkedHashMap");
maps.put(new Hashtable<Integer, String>(),"Hashtable");
```

Printing the map to logs will show only the last one added:

```
maps: {{}=Hashtable}
```

I tried with other Map implementations and all have the same behavior except TreeMap which will throw an exception due to the fact that HashMap does not implement `Comparable`.

Is this expected behavior? Why does HashMap behave like this?

Comment: Because `new HashMap<Integer, String>().equals(new TreeMap<Integer, String>())` evaluates to `true`, because that is the contract of [`Map::equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: All `new` maps are `equal` and have same `hashcode` (which is `0`). BTW it is preferred to use *immutable* values as map keys. Otherwise you are risking that at some point state of key will change so its hashcode and equals will not no longer return same results.

Comment: Using hash maps as map keys is questionable (same goes for objects of any other mutable class). However, if you must do it, you need to supply methods for computing the hash code and checking the equality for the entire map.

Comment: If your maps has different contents (were not all empty), they would be treated as separate keys in your outer map.

Comment: What @Pshemo said; note that the equals and hashCode semantics of implementations of Map is prescribed in the Javadoc of Map.

Comment: @White_King, is there any special reason to use _mutable maps_ as keys in another map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we take a look at the [documentation of `Map::equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), we see that this method

> Returns `true` if the given object is also a map and the two maps represent the same mappings. More formally, two maps `m1` and `m2` represent the same mappings if `m1.entrySet().equals(m2.entrySet())`.

Due to the [contract between `Object::equals` and `Object::hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), this means that those maps will also have the same hash code. This, in return, means that they are, for [`Map::put`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#put(K,V)), indistinguishable. Thus, each `put(...)` in the sample program overrides the previous `put` and thus results in a final map size of `1` with only the `HashTable` in the `entrySet()`.

So yes, this is expected behaviour. And it is not only expected for `HashMap`, but for all `Map` implementations.

As was already pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70583791/why-will-hashmap-ignore-entries-with-keys-from-the-same-superclass/70583874#comment124774172_70583791) by [Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo), it is questionable to use a `Map` as key for another `Map` and, in general, we should use immutable objects as keys.